# Виджет под Angular

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, angular, виджет

Есть готовый проект написанный на Angular + Spring Boot. Хочу пользователям дать возможность писать свои дополнения (свои виджеты). То есть пользователь пишет свой виджет, делает архив и загружает на сервер. И тут же у выделенном месте на сайте для этого пользователя отображается его виджет. Только для этого пользователя. Виджетов на странице может быть много.

Кто может подсказать какими технологиями и как это можно реализовать?

Было бы неплохо если бы виджет можно было писать на разных технологиях типа Angular, VueJS и тд. А не только на чистом JS. Но в целом можно что б и только на чистом JS.

Так же хотелось бы передавать некоторые данные со страницы у виджет что б пользователю не нужно было отправлять новый запрос на сервер.

Не совсем могу понять и разобраться как правильно реализовать этот функционал( С помощью iframe не очень нравится идея. Может есть ещё какие то варианты?

Comment: Вам наверное стоит почитать про микрофронтенды, если я правильно понял.

Comment: Я немного читал об этом, но на сколько я понял, каждый новый микрофронт подключается в основу до  сборки. То есть нужно сначала подключить, потом собрать проект, а уже дальше как только что то будет меняться в микро, то сразу же поменяется и в основе. А мне нужно, что бы сразу тянулось в основу без её пересборки.

Comment: Для апдейтов пересобирать нужно будет только сами микрофронтенды. Почитайте поподробнее, технология аналогична микросервисам на бэке.